# Twitter feedback widget for web pages?

Tags: twitter

For a web app I want to write/obtain an embeddable widget that will show visitors all the recent tweets with #myproduct.

I'd like an input box where users could give their feedback, hit submit, then be taken to twitter.com where they would see a prepared message their feedback + "#myproduct", ready for them to hit 'send' to send the tweet with their own Twitter credentials.

Is that possible? Or something similar possible? My app is on Google App Engine if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible and even easy.  Twitter allows you to preload a status message by including its text as a "status" parameter in the URL:  [Click here to tweet this.](http://twitter.com/?status=Click%20here%20to%20tweet%20this.)